# Lower bounds for period length of continued fraction of square root

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

EDIT: Dror answered this to my complete satisfaction. The simple continued fraction for $$ \sqrt{n^2 + 1}$$ has length exactly the same, no dependence on $n$!!!!! No lower bound of the type I wanted is possible.
The adjacent reduced indefinite binary quadratic forms in the complete cycle are 
$$ \langle 1, \; 2 n, \; -1 \rangle $$
$$ \langle -1, \; 2 n, \; 1 \rangle $$
$$ \langle 1, \; 2 n, \; -1 \rangle $$
for a cycle length of 2.

The first nontrivial solution to the $+1$ Pell equation becomes
$$ (2 n^2 + 1)^2 - ( n^2 + 1) (2 n)^2 = 1  $$

So no lower bound on cycle lengths can
depend only on the approximate size of the number of
which one is taking the square root, and all my crap below is useless. Oh, well, I put in the effort to write the question carefully, and I got an answer. There is still Dror's idea of short c.f's for $\sqrt n$ where $n$ avoids this kind of special pattern.

EDIT: evidently Schinzel studied these "sleepers, creepers, jeepers, etc." with known very short continued fraction lengths. So Dror had explicitly asked me whether I wanted to disregard those but I could not recognize the terminology and gave a misleading answer. So my method may be useless, but the revised question stands.

ORIGINAL QUESTION: This question began with Dror Speiser's answer to

[Upper bound of period length of continued fraction representation of very composite number square root](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22811/)

Dror has some ideas on how to proceed. Here is what I had in mind when I mentioned it.
This is a really open-ended problem, but should not be thought of as an open problem yet because I just made it up.

What I have in mind is the definition of some measurement of shortness $S(n)$ for the period length of the continued fraction for $\sqrt n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Then I am hoping an optimization problem and
for a sequence of numbers $n_t$ in the style of the colossaly abundant numbers, whereby $S(n_t)$ would automatically be better than $S(k)$ for any $k < n.$ The payoff could be explicit factorizations for the $n_t.$

A very nice paper on this is J. L. Nicolas, On highly composite numbers, pp. 215-244 in Ramanujan Revisited, Editors G. E. Andrews et al., Academic Press 1988. See also

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabundant_number

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number

Let me give some detail.

(I) The first step, and I am not utterly certain this is known, is do we even know for sure that the period lengths increase without bound? This would appear to be explicit in  Golubeva (1991),

http://www.springerlink.com/content/f11602324177865w/

(II) Next we need some explicit increasing lower bound $f(n).$ Let us define $l(n)$ as the period length of the continued fraction for $\sqrt n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Again, I do not know whether such a bound $f(n) \leq l(n)$ is known.

(III) Third is some tiny (but increasing) function $g(n)$ that grows so slowly that for any real $t > 1,$
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{(g(n))^t}{l(n)}    = 0.          $$
If it turns out to be suitable, we could just take $g(n) = \log f(n).$

(IV) It follows that $$   \frac{(g(n))^t}{l(n)} $$ achieves a maximum. If the maximum is achieved by only one value of $n,$ then that is the definition of $n_t.$ If the maximum is achieved at more than one value, take $n_t$ to be the largest of these (at least that is what is done with the superior highly composite numbers, although the point is not made clear in the Nicolas article).

(V) If I have got the order correct on the inequalities, we would hope to get a sequence $n_t$ that is constant on intervals $t_1 < t < t_2$ but eventually increases. The jump points at which $n_t$ increases would be of interest. With any luck, some reasonable measure of surprising shortness would be improving as the $n_t$ increase.  Finally, the most optimistic part of this is the possibility that, as in Nicolas and Alaoglu and Erdos before that and Ramanujan before that, there is an  explicit factorization of $n_t.$

Well, thanks for reading this far.

Comment: $l(n) < 3.76\sqrt{n}\log(n))$. See R. G. Stanton, C. Sudler, Jr., and H. C. Williams, An Upper Bound for the period of the Simple Continued Fraction for $\sqrt{D}$, Pacific Journal of
Mathematics , Vol. 67, No. 2, 1976, pp. 525-536. I also distinctively remember reading a paper saying something like $\sqrt{D}/R_o < l(n) < \sqrt{D}R_o$ but can't find it again (where $o$ is the order with discriminant associated to $D$ (which might be $4D$)).

Comment: What I remember about the lower bound to do with the regulator is obviously wrong (think of $n^2+1$). Maybe it was more like $R_o/log(\sqrt{D}) < l(n) < R_o log(\sqrt{D})$.

Comment: You mean 1. I think the question is a bit hard to understand, that's why I didn't realize you were looking for a lowest bound over all continued fractions. I thought you wanted to go over abundant discriminants or something. All's well that ends well :)

Comment: Yeah, I had mapped out this whole plan. Note that estimating things for $n!$ is still a valid problem, just not one I know anything about.

Comment: Will, your question starts with "edit". I wonder whether you have deleted the question itself by accident.

Comment: Wadim, I hope not, I got in the habit of putting in the word EDIT so that someone who had looked at one of my long posts could tell what was old and what was more recent. The status here is that Dror knew about the $n^2 + 1$ example all along, had asked me in Schinzel's terminology whether I wanted to disregard it, I misunderstood. So my post should be two "EDIT" s followed by my original question, which is very long already. The question of estimating cycle lengths for $n!$ and finding related sequences with short cycles stands, see Dror's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22811/ 

Comment: There are plenty more non-square $k > 1$ for which $\sqrt{k}$ has continued fraction of period-length at most 2:  precisely the integers $k = v(vm^2 + 4)/4$ with integers $v, m \ge 1$ such that $vm$ is even.  (Taking $v = 1$ gives the family $k = n^2 + 1$.) 

Comment: There are similar families of length 4.

Comment: Thank you, Brian and Douglas. Evidently Schinzel, possibly long ago, gave these families funny names, "sleepers, creepers, jeepers, etc." So Dror began looking for numbers with  short continued fraction periods considering their size, but not belonging to any of Schinzel's catalogued patterns. I actually noticed several of these when writing my final paper with Kaplansky, I just forgot. Anyway Dror has a plausible way to proceed, in a comment at the earlier question. I'd really like to know, well, what happens next.

Comment: @Will, I can only confirm how surprised I am by all this info about CFs for square roots. I didn't pay too much attention to the primorial-factorial question as I couldn't imagine that those CFs are "shorter" than others. A great chance for me to vote for very good reasons.

Comment: In fact, Shcinzel only studied and dubbed the name sleepers. It was Kaplansky who dubbed the name creepers.

Comment: BTW, mathoverflow.net/questions/23153 has an ultimate link to continued fractions.

Comment: My current interpretation of two papers (out of several related) by Elena P. Golubeva, until I see translations, is that there for any length $k,$ not just 1,2,4, there are infinitely many d with  continued fraction period length $k$ if there are any. 
  1991: http://www.springerlink.com/content/f11602324177865w/ 
1997 downloadable in Russian: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/journal.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=znsl&paperid=424&year=1997&volume=237&issue=&fpage=31&lpage=39&option_lang=eng  

1997 English info: http://www.springerlink.com/content/r5n2462km18u0t13/ 


Comment: To continue, if this is correct, then the more reasonable problem is to talk about  $\sqrt d$ for $d$ in certain sequences not primarily defined by quadratic polynomials. Golubeva does primes, the earlier question was about $d=n!$ or "primorial," I mentioned superior highly composite numbers, Dror thought of numbers with many small prime factors squared, and so on. I really misunderstood this whole framework

Comment: Hi Will, I'll check with Golubeva's contributions (just because I can read Russian without dictionary :) and access mathnet as a former member of the Steklov Institute), but I'll ask some experts in Moscow about these as well.

Comment: Schinzel characterized all "sleepers" in Acta Arith. 6 (1960/1961), 393-413; MR0125814 (23 #A3111) and Acta Arith. 7 (1961/1962), 287-298; MR0139566 (25 #2998), but I don't think he used that word. Kaplansky came up with the terms sleepers, leapers, and creepers in a 1998 memo to Mollin, Hugh Williams, and Ken Williams. See also Mollin, R. A.and Cheng, K., Beepers, creepers, and sleepers, Int. Math. J. 2 (2002), no. 9, 951--956, MR1919684 (2003f:11011). Patterson and van der Poorten add kreepers and jeepers in their paper in the book, High Primes and Misdemeanours. 


Comment: Thank you, Gerry. The mystery is why I don't remember Kap's letter on this. We shared an office and he gave me copies of most things. Perhaps he felt this was not one of the topics we had been discussing.  I found an item related to High Primes, www.maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/SomeRecentPapers/177.pdf 

Anyway, I'm waiting on confirmation of the idea that there are infinitely many continued fractions of square roots with any fixed period length.    

Comment: The Patterson and van der Poorten paper (or possibly a draft of it) is at http://www.maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/SomeRecentPapers/171.pdf

Comment: The links to Golubeva's papers at `springerlink.com` are broken. I'm unable to find any snapshots saved on the Wayback Machine, either.

Comment: The post linked in [Wadim Zudilin's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23134/lower-bounds-for-period-length-of-continued-fraction-of-square-root#comment47971_23134) is '[Frobenius number for three numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23153/183188)'. (I'm just reposting it as an actual link so that it appears in the right sidebar under the "Linked" questions list.)

Comment: Reposting a link mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/47889) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: [Upper bound of period length of continued fraction representation of very composite number square root](https://mathoverflow.net/q/22811)