# Frobenius number for three numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Given integers $a,b,c$ such that $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$, it is well known that there exists only a finite set of numbers $n$ such that $n$ is not expressible as $ax+by+cz$ for non negative integers $x$,$y$,$z$.

It is also known that there exists a quadratic time algorithm for finding the maximal such $n$. However I was not able to spot the paper covering the algorithm.

Anybody happens to know the algorithm and/or a (free) reference to it?

Comment: 2016 update: Amitabha Tripathi has an article in press called "Formulae for the Frobenius number in three variables" to be published in the Journal of Number Theory. I haven't seen it yet so I can't compare it to the Einstein-Lichtblau-Strzebonski-Wagon algorithm. Video abstract here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv0GSy2MGzw

Comment: @Charles the Tripathi paper is now available at http://web.iitd.ac.in/~atripath/publications/FP_3-var.pdf (J. Number Theory 170 (2017) 368-389) and it was discussed very briefly at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292152/tripathis-formulas-for-frobenius-number-in-three-variables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple algoritm based on continued fractions was proposed by Rödseth, O. J. On a linear Diophantine problem of Frobenius J. Reine Angew. Math., 1978, 301, 171-178

All algorithm are described in Ramrez Alfonsn, J. L. The Diophantine Frobenius problem Oxford University Press, 2005

I think that Mathematica uses Rödseth's algoritm http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PositiveFrobeniusNumbersOfThreeArguments/

Comment: The algorithm can be found here: http://books.google.com/books?id=xk978NpQkn8C&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=R%C3%B8dseth%E2%80%99s+Algorithm&source=bl&ots=uwWFmuz8Na&sig=gEbbUkP1pvZDHxhI_JP0YOGRULE&hl=en&ei=kjTcS_GOEM-XOLW9_KEH&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=R%C3%B8dseth%E2%80%99s%20Algorithm&f=false

The first line of the algorithm computes $s_0$ such that $s_0a_2 = a_3 \mod a_1$ given $1 \leq a_1 < a_2 <a_3$ such that $gcd(a_1,a_2,a_3) = 1$.  Am I missing something or is not always possible to compute $s_0$? For example for $6,10,15$?

Comment: First of all you must use Johnson's formula. For modified Frobenius number $f(a,b,c)=g(a,b,c)+a+b+c$ it gives $f(a,b,c)=d f(a/d,b/d,c)$. It allows to reduce calculation of $f(a,b,c)$ to the case $(a,b)=(a,c)=(b,c)=1$.

Comment: For example $f(6,10,15)=2f(3,5,15)=6f(1,5,5)=30f(1,1,1)=60$, $g(6,10,15)=60-6-10-15=29$.

Comment: Mathematica does not use Rodseth. It uses the very fast algorithm described in our paper in INTEGERS and cited in my answer. This works even for 10000-digit or longer numbers. I believe the algorithm's complexity is "softly linear": O(n^(1+epsilon)). THe specific case of n = 3 is discussed in detail in our paper.

Stan Wagon

Comment: It is strange, because for $n=3$ Rodseth is just extended GCD algorithm. In the worst case it requares $O(\log^2 N)$ operations (and it is known that comlexity can be reduced to $O(\log^{1+\epsilon} N)$). Is your algorithm faster?

Comment: Sorry -- I might have erred in my thoughts on Rodseth. And, yes, I said "n" where I mean log N. Reviewing our INTEGERS paper (INTEGERS, 7 (2007) #A15, 63 pp. <http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/vol7.html>), I see that our section 5 goes into a lot of details on the n=3 case: We use ideas of Eisenbrand-Rote for some speedups. But overall complexity is still softly linear. Seems a little more complicated than just an extended GCD.

Answer (score 11):

This is addressed in our paper

Frobenius numbers by lattice point enumeration, David Einstein, Daniel Lichtblau, Adam Strzebonski, and Stan Wagon, INTEGERS, 7 (2007) #A15, 63 pp. <http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/vol7.html>

Answer (score 4):

Rödseth formula for Frobenius numbers is good not only for computation. It allows to find weak asymptotic for Frobenius numbers with three arguments and density function for normalized Frobenius numbers.

*A. V. Ustinov, “The solution of Arnold's problem on the weak asymptotics of Frobenius numbers with three arguments”, Mat. Sb., 200:4 (2009), 131–160*

*Shchur, V.; Sinai, Y.; Ustinov, A. Limiting distribution of Frobenius numbers for n = 3 Journal of Number Theory, 2009, 129, 2778–2789*

Answer (score 3):

The following paper seems to be the first to do what you want:

> MR0955143 (89j:11122)
>   Greenberg, Harold(1-CUNY2-S)
>   Solution to a linear Diophantine equation for nonnegative integers.
>   J. Algorithms 9 (1988), no. 3, 343--353.

$   $

> The paper contains a fundamental improvement in the theory of linear Diophantine equations with three variables. Let $1 < a< b < c $ and $L$ be positive integers. Following the results of \n O. J. Rødseth\en [J. Reine Angew. Math. 301 (1978), 171--178; MR0557016 (58 #27741)] the author gives an algorithm using only $O(\log a)$ steps to generate a nonnegative solution of the linear Diophantine equation $ax+by+cz=L$. Applying this algorithm the author provides us with another algorithm, requiring $O(\log a)$ steps as well, to solve the Frobenius problem with three variables, i.e., to determine the number $\max\{L\in\mathbb{Z} \ | \  \nexists (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{Z}_+^3,\ ax+by+cz=L\}$ assuming that $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$. (Mathscinet review by Béla Vizvári)

I couldn't myself get my hands on a copy of this paper.  The same holds for a 1994 J. Number Theory paper of J.L. Davison, which also gives a quadratic algorithm for computing the Frobenius number in the case of $3$ weights.

The most relevant publically available thing I could find (which seems pretty relevant, although I didn't look to see exactly what they say about the $n = 3$ case as opposed to the general case) is a 2005 paper of Beihoffer, Hendry, Nijenhuis and Wagon published in the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics:

http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_12/Abstracts/v12i1r27.html

Comment: Yeah. I've seen that one mentioned in a few papers. The only problem seem to be that it is not freely accessible online.

Answer (score 2):

Several expository papers about the Frobenius problem and its generalizations can be found on Jeffrey Shallit's web page:

http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/talks.html

and a more technical journal article is linked here:

http://www.springerlink.com/content/655j4t10575052h7/

Comment: The link to the article at `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also not able to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudocode for the Bocker-Liptak algorithm:

```
Let a be the numbers a[1], a[2], ... a[k]
Lay out a[1] tiles (numbered 1 thru a[1]) on which to write numbers
Write 0 on tile 1
for i in [2, ..., k]
    find gcd(a[1], a[i])
    d = gcd(a[1], a[i])
    for starting tile r in [1, ..., d]
        let nn be the smallest number on tiles r, r + d, ...;
        if there are no numbers written on those tiles, go to the next starting tile
        else repeat the following floor(a[1]/d) times
            add a[i] to nn
            let p be nn mod a[1]
            go to tile p
            if there is nothing there, write nn
            else write min(nn, what is there)

When done, subtract a[1] from the largest number written on the tiles: this the
Frobenius number for the given values in `a`.
```

Here is Python code for the algorithm that I have modified:

````
    def frobenius_number(*a):
        """
        Return the first number past which all numbers divisible by
        the gcd of the numbers can be made from non-negative multiples
        of positive integers in `a`; also report the gcd of the numbers.

        >>> frobenius_number(6,9,20)
        (43, 1)

        Any number larger than 43 can be created from combinations
        of 6, 9 and 20.

        >>> frobenius_number(20, 44)
        (159, 4)

        Starting at 160, all multiples of 4 can be made from
        combinations of 20 and 44.
        """

        from sympy import igcd

        # modified Bocker-Liptak implementation from https://brg.a2hosted.com/?page_id=563

        def __residue_table(a):
            from collections import defaultdict
            n = defaultdict(None)
            n[0] = 0
            for i in range(1, len(a)):
                d = igcd(a[0], a[i])
                for r in range(d):
                    try: nn = min(n.get(q) for q in range(r, a[0], d) if q in n)
                    except ValueError: continue  # e.g. a = 2,4,5 or 4,6,7
                    for _ in range(a[0] // d):
                        nn += a[i]
                        p = nn % a[0]
                        if n.get(p) is not None:
                            nn = min(nn, n[p])
                        n[p] = nn
            return n

        a = [i for i in a if i]
        if len(a) == 0 or any(i < 0 for i in a):
            raise ValueError
        if len(a) == 1:
            return -(a[0] - 1)
        g = igcd(*a)
        if g != 1:
            n = frobenius_number(*[i // g for i in a])[0]
            return g * (n + 1) - 1, g
        a = sorted(a)
        return max(__residue_table(a).values()) - a[0], 1
```
````

Comment: I don't think anyone else has so much as mentioned any Bocker-Liptak algorithm. Can you add a few words about when and where it was published, maybe a plain-English summary of how it works, some idea of how it compares with the other algorithms that we've seen here? We aren't all fluent in Python.

Comment: This algorithm was published in Algorithmica in 2007. A glimpse is available here with other references to more recent work on this computation: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00453-007-0162-8 . It is `O(k*a1)`. It is similar to the Eratosthenes method of finding primes; I have also seen it referred to as a round-robin approach. I will annotate the code.