# Fifth powers modulo a prime

Tags: nt.number-theory

This is related to Victor Protsak's approach to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26358/can-we-color-z-with-n-colors-such-that-a-2a-na-all-have-different-colors).

> Suppose that $p\gt 11$ is a prime of
>   the form $5n+1$. Can we prove that
>   $1^5,2^5,\dots,n^5$ *cannot* be
>   pairwise different modulo $p$?

I ran a quick computer search, and this is indeed the case for $p\le 5\times 42806+1=214031$. In fact, $|\{ i^k\pmod p: 1\le i\le n\}|/n$ stays rather close to 0.672...

It is not hard to answer the same question with 3 in the place of 5: There are no primes of the form $3n+1$ with $1^3,2^3,\dots,n^3$ distinct modulo $p$. Quickly, $-3$ is a quadratic residue of any $p$ of the form $3n+1$. One easily checks that (modulo $p$) there must be a $y$ such that $y^2=-3$ and either $x=y-1\ne 1$ or $x=(y-1)/2\ne 2$ is in the interval $[1,n]$. But then $(x+1)^2=-3$ so $x^3=8$, or $(2x+1)^2=-3$ so $x^3=1$.

If instead of 3 we use a number of the form $4k$, then there are only finitely many primes $p=4nk+1$ for which $1^{4k},\dots,n^{4k}$ are distinct modulo $p$ (but there may be such $p$; for example, if $4k=84$, then we can take $n=5$). This is because there are $x,y$ with $1\le x\lt y$ and $x^2+y^2=p$, so $x^{4k}\equiv y^{4k}\pmod p$, and if $p$ is slightly larger than $(4k)^2$, then $y\le n$.

(Of course one can ask the same question with any $k$ in the place of $5$, and I suspect that as long as $k>2$, the answer is always that there are only finitely many values of $n$ for which the powers are distinct. But I also suspect that this is going to be significantly harder than for $k=5$. I would be delighted for suggestions or approaches towards this more general case.)

Comment: This is probably wrong or otherwise too easy: If the powers $1^5$, $2^5$, ..., $n^5$ would be distinct modulo $p$, then they would be a list of *all* $5$-th powers modulo $p$ (since $p=5n+1$, so there are only $n$ $5$-th powers modulo $p$), so their sum would be the sum of all distinct $5$-th powers modulo $p$, and that latter sum is known to be $\equiv 0\mod p$ (see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=40171 ). In other words, we would have $1^5+2^5+...+n^5\equiv 0\mod p$. But $1^5+2^5+...+n^5=\frac{1}{12}n^2\left(n+1\right)^2\left(2n^2+2n-1\right)$, and some ...

Comment: As $-1$ has to be a $5$-th power, you need the prime $p$ to be a fifth power plus $1$.

Comment: ... polynomial division shows that each of $n$, $n+1$ and $2n^2+2n-1$ is coprime to $5n+1=p$ unless $p=11$.

Comment: @Darij: Your point being that for $p = 5n+1$ prime, it has to divide one of the factors?


Comment: @darij: Ah, ok, you are right, the same observation should deal with the general case. Sorry, this turned out to be too easy, I wasn't thinking about this appropriately. Would you like to write this as an answer? Otherwise, I'll wait a bit and write something myself. 

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Andres: The general case seeems much more interesting; I wouldn't say that it is dealt with by my argument. Probably it will use some congruences with Stirling and Bernoulli numbers. If you have something useful in the way of solving it, please post it!

Comment: Oh, of course, it is clear that for every $k$, it will work for all but finitely many values of $n$, unless the polynomial $kn+1$ divides the polynomial $1^k+2^k+...+n^k$. The question is when this happens, and what are the finitely many values of $n$ otherwise.

Comment: @darij Could you please just post your nice solution?  By the way, you can refine the method by taking $jk$th powers for various $j$.

Comment: @Greg (and everybody else wondering): I may have answered the question, but I haven't answered the Question, namely the case of $k$ general. I feel that at least the non-divisibility of the polynomial $1^k+2^k+...+n^k$ by $kn+1$ is a doable (i. e., not entirely out of reach), yet nontrivial problem, and whoever solves it should be considered the actual answerer of this question. But if Andres feels he is not interested in that, he is free to self-answer the question with my proof. I have enough undeserved rep here already since the alg geo question I posted some weeks ago (if not earlier).

Comment: @darij Experimental fact (i.e., SAGE-supported conjecture):  Let $f(x,k)$ be the polynomial interpolation of $1^k + 2^k + \cdots + x^k$.  Then $k^{k+1}f(-1/k,k)$ is 1 mod $k$ when $k$ is odd and $(k-2)/2$ mod $k$ when $k$ is even.

Comment: Note also that (in the general question) if $a$ is any $k$th root of unity mod $p$, then $1,2,\ldots,n$ is disjoint from $a,2a,\ldots,an$ mod $p$, assuming that $p$ is a counterexample to Andres' question.  I conjecture that this disjointness property is impossible unless either $p$ is small or $a = -1$, even without other restrictions on $a$.

Comment: I think I have solved the general problem, using a result of Inkeri's. See below.

Comment: @Greg: just saw your comment ("...I conjecture that this disjointness property is impossible unless either $p$ is small or $a=−1$..."); you're right, see my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following Darij Grinberg's comments I obtained

**Theorem.** For any integer $k>2$ there are only finitely many primes of the form $p=kn+1$ such that $1^k,2^k,\dots,n^k$ are distinct modulo $p$.

**Proof.** Assume that $k,n>2$ and $p=kn+1$ is a prime such that $1^k,2^k,\dots,n^k$ are distinct modulo $p$. Then the list represents the $k$-th powers modulo $p$, a cyclic group of order $n$. As a result, their squares $1^{2k},2^{2k},\dots,n^{2k}$ represent the $2k$-th powers modulo $p$ with multiplicity $1$ or $2$ depending on whether $n$ is odd or even. At any rate, $p$ divides their sum
$$ \sum_{m=1}^n m^{2k}=\frac{1}{2k+1}B_{2k+1}(n+1), $$ 
where $B_{2k+1}(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ denotes the $(2k+1)$-th Bernoulli polynomial. Here we used $p-1>2k$ and the vanishing of the $(2k+1)$-th Bernoulli number. By a result of Inkeri (see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa50/aa5033.pdf)) the linear factors of $B_{2k+1}(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ are $x$, $x-1/2$, $x-1$, hence $x+1/k$ is certainly coprime to $B_{2k+1}(x+1)$. It follows that there is an integer $N>0$ and polynomials $u(x),v(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ depending on $k$ such that
$$ u(x)(kx+1)+v(x)B_{2k+1}(x+1)=N. $$
By plugging $x=n$ we see that $p$ divides $N$, hence $p$ can only take finitely many values depending on $k$.

Comment: But it does seem that Darij is too modest.

Comment: Great! Many thanks for both the answer and the reference. I'll accept this in a few hours. Meanwhile, a master's student is writing a note on a series of related topics. Would you mind emailing me your name (caicedo@math.boisestate.edu) so we can attribute the result properly?

Comment: @Andres: I sent you an email.

Answer (score 15):

[*Edited to describe triple and higher-order coincidences for prime $k$, recovering the observed $0.672$ proportion for $k=5$*]

Darij's pretty argument, extended by GH, nicely answers the question for $k$-th powers modulo a large prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod k$ for each fixed $k>2$.  Yet more can be said: that approach yields the existence of one coincidence $a^k \equiv b^k$ with $0 < a < b < p/k\phantom.$; but in fact the number of coincidences is asymptotically proportional to $p$: the count is $C_k \phantom. p + O_k(p^{1-\epsilon(k)})$, where $C_k = (k-1)/(2k^2)$ or $(k-2)/(2k^2)$ according as $k$ is odd or even, and $\epsilon(k) = 1/\varphi(k) \geq 1/(k-1)$.
Extending the analysis to triple and higher-order coincidences also yields the asymptotic proportion of $k$-th powers that arise in $\lbrace a^k \phantom. \bmod p : a < p/k \rbrace$.  For example, when $k$ is an odd prime, the proportion of $k$-th powers that *do not* have a $k$-th root in $(0,p/k)$ is asymptotic to $((k-1)^k+1)/k^k$; for $k=5$ that's $41/125$, so the proportion *with* such a $k$-th root is $84/125$, which matches A.Caicedo's observed $0.672$ exactly.  It also gives $1 - \frac{8+1}{27} = 2/3$ for $k=3$, matching the proportion of cubes reported by Greg Martin in comments below; as $k \rightarrow \infty$ the proportion of $k$-th powers with small $k$-th roots approaches $1 - (1/e)$.

Here's how to estimate the number of pairs.  Begin with the observation that $a^k = b^k$ **iff** $b \equiv ma \bmod p$ where $m$ is one of the $k-1$ solutions of $m^k \equiv 1 \bmod p$ other than $m=1$.  If $k$ is even, we exclude also $m=-1$, which is impossible with $0<a,b<p/k$.  Then $b \equiv ma \bmod p$ defines a lattice of index $p$ in ${\bf Z}^2$ all of whose nonzero vectors have length $\gg p^{\epsilon(k)}$, because for such a vector $p$ divides the nonzero number $a^k-b^k$, which factors into homogeneous polynomials in $a,b$ each of degree at most $\phi(k)$.  [This is where we use $m \neq -1$: if $a=-b$ then $a^k-b^k=0$.]  Thus the solutions of $b \equiv ma \bmod p$ with $a,b \in (0,p/k)$ are the lattice points in a square of area $(p/k)^2$, and their number is estimated by $p^{-1} (p/k)^2 = p/k^2$, with an error bound proportional to (perimeter)/(length of shortest nonzero vector), i.e. proportional to $p^{1-\epsilon(k)}$.  The total of $C_k \phantom. p + O_k(p^{1-\epsilon(k)})$ then follows by summing over all $k-1$ or $k-2$ solutions of $m^k=1 \bmod p$ other than $m = \pm 1$, and dividing by 2 because we've counted each coincidence twice, as $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$.

Likewise one can estimate the counts of triples etc.  One must be careful with subsets of the $k$-th roots of unity that have integer dependencies, but at least when $k$ is prime there are no dependencies except that all $k$ of them sum to zero.  If I did this right, the result for $j<k$ is that the number of $j$-element subsets of $\lbrace 1, 2, \ldots, (p-1)/k \rbrace$ with the same $k$-th power is asymptotic to ${k \choose j} p / k^{j+1}$, while there are no such subsets with $j=k$ because the sum of all $k$ solutions of $a^k \equiv c \bmod p$ vanishes.  An exercise in generatingfunctionological inclusion-exclusion then produces the formula $((k-1)^k+1)/k^k$ for the asymptotic proportion of $k$-th powers that have no $k$-th roots at all in $(0,p/k)$.

The same technique also works for $0 < a < b < M$ with $M$ considerably smaller than $p/k$; and the resulting coincidences, when they exist, can be calculated efficiently using lattice basis reduction (which as it happens I mentioned on this forum [a few days ago](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77986)).

Comment: Oh, this is really nice! I didn't expect there would be such a clean argument explaining the proportions I had been observing. Many thanks!

Comment: I compute $C_5 = 2/25$, so that the proportion of distinct $5$th powers among the first $n$ is $(\frac15-\frac2{25})/\frac15 = 0.6$. How does this match the observed value of $0.672$ from the question (which I duplicated with my own observations)?

Both $C_3 = 1/9$ and $C_4=1/16$ (yielding proportions $2/3$ and $3/4$ for $k=3,4$ respectively) do match my observed data, but $k=5$ seems off.

Comment: @Greg Martin: Once $k>4$ the same $k$-th power can arise more than twice.  For example, $1^5 \equiv 2^5 \equiv 4^5 \equiv 1 \bmod 31$ yields three $(a,b)$ pairs, and $19^5 \equiv 22^5 \equiv 31^5 \equiv 35^5 \equiv 19 \bmod 181$ yields six.  (You can't have all five fifth roots in $(0,p/5)$ because they sum to zero.)

Comment: ... and in fact 0.672 is exactly right: the same kind of analysis shows that there are asymptotically $2p/5^3$ triples and $p/5^4$ quadruples, which means that the proportion of fifth powers that arise 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 times is 41/125, 51/125, 26/125, 6/125, 1/125 respectively; and $1 - \frac{41}{125} = \frac{84}{125} = 0.672$ on the nose.