# A three variable linear diophantine promise problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory, mathematical-software

Given $a,b,c,s\in\Bbb N$ such that $(a,b,c)=1$ with promise that we have at most one triple $x,y,z\in\Bbb N$ such that $ax+by+cz=s$, what is a good algorithm that runs in $O(\log(abcs))$ time to find such a triple or return empty?

I am trying to use FrobeniusSolve as recommended in the comments in this accepted answer here [Frobenius number for three numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23153/frobenius-number-for-three-numbers). However it seems pretty slow (that is does not seem logarithmic in $abcs$).

What is the complexity of this method that is implemented in $\mathsf{mathematica}$? Is there an $O(\log(abcs))$ time complexity method or something close to it?

Answer (score 1):

It is almost the Frobenius problem for three variables, where many results are known. Modifying your equation as $$ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=n,$$ where $x_i\geq 0$ and $n=s-a-b-c$ yields a Frobenius problem. See this related mathoverflow link: [Frobenius number for three numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23153/frobenius-number-for-three-numbers). Mathematica has a procedure to determine all solutions: [FrobeniusSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Frobenius.html).

Comment: pardon me but these seem to be talking about Frobenius number calculation. I actually want to find $(x,y,x)\in\Bbb N^3$. Do these algorithms do that in $O(\log(abcs))$ time? Could you post the correct paper?

Comment: See Pete L. Clark's answer: [http://mathoverflow.net/a/23155/74606]. Greenberg provided an algorithm using only $O(\log a)$ steps to generate a nonnegative solution of the linear Diophantine equation $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=n$.

Comment: I saw that too and the paper. What is a 'step'? What is total arithmetic operations? Is each step $O(\log(abcs))$ arithmetic operations?

Comment: What kind of timings have you obtained? Since you have the promise to have at most one solution you should try FrobeniusSolve[{a,b,c},n,1].

Comment: E.g. FrobeniusSolve[{12111139,13573321,29991743},29999999980,1] takes less than a second to find $x_1=619, x_2=1543, x_3=52.$