# Tripathi's formulas for Frobenius number in three variables

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Recently (January 2017) a paper by A. Tripathi has been published in the Journal of Number Theory with "closed" formulas for the Frobenius number in 3 variables ([Formulae for the Frobenius number in three variables](http://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X16301743)).

**Question:** Have Tripathi's formulas less computational complexity than already known algorithms (Greenberg, Rödseth) in some case?

Comment: I think we decided some time ago that MO was not a suitable place for fishing expeditions on recent publications.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch I've specified my question.

Comment: A better (for this forum) formulation would be "has there been any recent comparison or evaluation of these results against classical algorithms?  While endorsement would be nice, I am interested in relative performance for computational purposes." , or something like this, which is more free of opinion and more possibility to be objective. If the question is made even more objective, I will vote to reopen. Gerhard "One Less Than Four For's" Paseman, 2018.02.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Rödseth's formula for Frobenius number gives an algorithm with the same complexity as Euclidean algorithm. Unlikely any other algorithm will be better.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov But according to Wikipedia, Greenberg's algorithm has less worst-case complexity than Rödseth's, so it looks like there is some room available (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup#R%C3%B6dseth's_algorithm)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Original Rödseth's algorithm can be easely improved because negative continued fraction is a simple transformation of usual continued fraction. I kept in mind this improvement as Rödseth's algorithm. As I understand it is the same as Greenberg's algorithm.