# Lower bounds (or less) for the period of sqrt(D) and related sequences

Tags: continued-fractions, open-problems

This is a continuation of [Lower bounds for period length of continued fraction of square root](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23134/) which is a continuation of [Upper bound of period length of continued fraction representation of very composite number square root](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22811/).

Yesterday, I came across a nice article with many problems on continued fractions of Michel Mendes France (from 1993):

http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/fr/view?rid=ensmat-001:1993:39::498&id=&id2=&id3= (broken link)

In problem 6 he asks: Let $x$ be quadratic irrational and $\pi(x)$ the length of its period. Is $sup_n(\pi(x^n))=\infty$?

Is this problem still open? I saw many articles about upper bounds for $\pi(\sqrt{D})$ but none on lower bounds (expect the Golubeva one that is mentioned in the first mentioned question, but due to lack of background, I fail to understand the results there).

As Will Jagy asked: Do we even know whether  $[\pi(\sqrt{n})):n\in \mathbb N]$ is bounded or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** The following argument has an error in the second paragraph. I claimed that
the set $\{ D^n\sqrt{D} (\mod 1)\}$ has uncountably many accumulation points, but as
Sam Nead points out in the comments, this doesn't follow from $\sqrt{D}$ being
irrational. On the other hand, it is true that the set $\{ \sqrt{n}(\mod 1)\}$ is
uniformly distributed, and therefore that $\sup \pi(\sqrt{n}) =\infty$. 
This is because $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. See a paper of [Elkies
and McMullen](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/sqrts/sqrts.pdf) for related information on the distribution of this set.
The issue is here that the set of accumulation points of $\{ x^n \mod 1\}$ for
$x$ irrational may be a countable set. This question is actually discussed in Mendes'
paper referred to in the question (I should have looked at it more closely before!). 
As pointed out in that paper, [this can occur for Pisot numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot_number) Also, the
statement is proved by [Grisel for many quadratic numbers](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa74/aa7426.pdf) (as mentioned in a note to Mendes paper). * See also [another paper of Grisel.](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa85/aa8513.pdf)

<strike>I think I can show that $sup_n(\pi(x^n))=\infty$ when $x=\sqrt{D}$.</strike>

---

Suppose that $x$ is an irrational, non-quadratic number in the interval $(0,1)$, 
and $n_i$ is a sequence of integers such that $\underset{i\to\infty}{\lim} \sqrt{n_i} (\mod 1) = x$. Then the claim is that $\pi(\sqrt{n_i})$
is unbounded. Basically, since $x$ has non-repeating continued fraction expansion, one can show that the continued fraction expansions of $\sqrt{n_i}$ have unbounded period. One can see this geometrically, by noting that there is an element of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ fixing $\pm \sqrt{n_i}$, and fixing the hyperbolic geodesic in $\mathbb{H}^2$ joining these two points. If $a^2-n_i c^2=\pm 1$ is the minimal solution to the Pell equation, then the matrix is:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & cn_i \\\ c & a\end{bmatrix}$$

Moreover, the pattern of horoballs which the geodesic penetrates in the Farey packing

[image: Farey packing] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/gallery/fuchs/farey.gif)

tells you the periodic continued fraction. When we take $\sqrt{n_i} (\mod 1)$, these geodesics shifted by $-\left[ \sqrt{n_i} \right]$ approach the vertical geodesic through $x$, whose Farey pattern gives the continued fraction expansion for $x$. Therefore $\pi(\sqrt{n_i})$ is unbounded.

Now we have to understand the continued fractions of $\sqrt{D^{2n+1}} = D^n \sqrt{D}$, where $D$ is squarefree. The accumulation points of $D^n \sqrt{D} (\mod 1)$ correspond to the truncations of the base $D$ representation of $\sqrt{D}$.  <strike>Since $\sqrt{D}$ is irrational, the limit points of these numbers in $[0,1]$ will be uncountable, and therefore contains a non-quadratic irrational $x$ which is a limit of $\sqrt{D^{2n_i+1}} (\mod 1)$, as $n_i\to \infty$. So we see that $\pi(\sqrt{D^{2n_i+1}}) \to \infty$.</strike>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the statement "Since $\sqrt{D}$ is irrational, the limit points of these numbers in $[0,1]$  will be uncountable".  

<p>For example, consider the number $\alpha = \sum 1/2^{2^n}$ and then the set $2^n \cdot \alpha\,(\mod 1)$.  It looks to me like the closure of this set is countable, with accumulation points only at $1/2^m$.  Am I missing something? 

<p>If not, then perhaps your argument can be saved using the fact that $\sqrt{D}$ is a much nicer number than $\alpha$.  In any case, I'm off to plot the points $2^n\sqrt{2}\,(\mod 1)$ on my computer. Fun!

Comment: I vaguely remember another reason to worry here: the powers of $(1 + \sqrt{5})/2$, taken modulo $1$, only accumulate on zero and one?

Comment: I used Sage to spit out the first 10000 bits of $\sqrt{2}$ and then ran a few tests.  Looks pretty random to me!  I also found various papers (eg Good and Grover) that ran statistical tests on the binary expansion, thus experimentally verifying its normality. 

Comment: Sage and the literature also suggest that $\sqrt{10}$ is normal in base $10$ (grin!).  Since base two and ten are the only ones I know how to extract from Sage, perhaps I should stop here.

Comment: Thanks for the information!- Agol, I lack the knowledge to understand your argument - where can I read about Farey packing and the relation of geodesics to continued fraction?

Comment: Probably a better way to think about it is the Farey tessellation. This perspective is discussed here:
http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNpage.html

Comment: @sam - can you give a reference for the powers of (1+\sqrt{5})2 , taken modulo 1 , only accumulate on zero and one?

Comment: @sam: also, can you give references for Good and Grover statistical tests? (by the way where do find these? I looked on Mathscinet without any success...)

Comment: @ Menny: $((1+\sqrt{5})/2)^n + ((1-\sqrt{5})/2)^n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

I just came across an interesting Ph.D. thesis by Roger Patterson which is very relevant to this topic: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703519v1

There are some $D$ which have unusually short continued fraction periods:

If $D = n^2 + 1$, and the CF of $\sqrt{D}$ is $[n,\overline{2n}]$

If $D = n^2 + 4$ and $n$ odd then the CF of $\sqrt{D}$ is $[n,\overline{\frac{n-1}{2},1,1,\frac{n-1}{2},2n}]$

There are others given in the thesis that I refer to.  He treats various families with unusually short periods and discusses a guess of Kaplansky that these are the only ones with unusually short periods (more precise definitions are given in the paper).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is relevant: following Mendes-France's paper and on his advice,
I wrote a paper in Acta Arithmetica (1975?) showing in particular that if you
multiply any periodic CF by a rational number $r$ the new period length is
always between $1/f(r)$ and $f(r)$ times the old period length, for an explicit function $f$. For instance $f(2)=5$, so when you multiply by $2$ the period
length is at most multiplied by $5$ (and of course at least $1/5$ of the
initial length).